# Inequality with Stirling's numbers of the second kind

Tags: co.combinatorics

Prove inequality:

$ S(n,k-1)\cdot S(n,k+1) \le (S(n,k))^2 $

for $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

I think induction is the last resort. I don't know if it will work but I rather want to avoid it.

Comment: A google search with the keywords "Stirling numbers" and "log-concave" gives several hits, like http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/040_4_0693.pdf and http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Zeilberger590-602.pdf .

Comment: Asked and answered at m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118029/proof-strategy-stirling-numbers-formula - voting to close. 

Comment: @darij grinberg
I don't understand why in ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/040_4_0693.pdf the inductive step is on $n$. Why does it work..